# Communicating with attendance device and retrieving data in c#.net application

Tags: c#

I have a ZKTeco time and attendance device of model IN01. I am trying to connect it with a C# windows form application. I registered the 64 bit version of Zkemkeeper.dll in SysWOW64 folder. I have the following code:

```
 zkemkeeper.CZKEM axCZKEM1 = new zkemkeeper.CZKEM();
bool bIsConnected;
    bIsConnected = axCZKEM1.Connect_Net(192.168.1.201, Convert.ToInt32(4370));
           //    bIsConnected = axCZKEM1.Connect_Com(Convert.ToInt32(4370), 1, 9600);

   if (bIsConnected == true)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Device Connected Successfully");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Device Not Connect");

                }
```

But I got the message from else part :

> communicating with ip or using serial communication

Using puTTy I am able to communicate with both ssh and serial port. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `SysWOW64` is only used by the system as a mirrof of `System32` for 32bit processes running on 64-bit OSs.. You shouldn't put *anything* in there. In fact, you shouldn't put anything in any system folder. All the dlls you need should be placed in the application's folder

Comment: Put it in your application's folder. `regsvr32` works with any path. Registration should be your installers responsibility anyway. You shouldn't copy dlls manually

Comment: I put it inside application's folder too but that didn't work. It didn't show me an error message but returns false everytym.

Comment: When I try debugging in 64 bit I get message from else part and when i try debugging using x86 , I get the message:     Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00853A19-BD51-419B-9269-2DABE57EB61F} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

Answer (score 1):

Since "*new zkemkeeper.CZKEM();*" is passed, then we can confirm that COM dll is registered successfully and the application has loaded the DLL successfully.

This looks like the network issue. Few workarounds:

- Check subnet mask, gateway between device and the computer are same
- Try changing the IP at the device and execute your application with updated IP
- Read the axCZKEM1.GetLastError and check the error code, if there is any

Note that, the device is not too intelligent as the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `Connect_Net` is expecting a string for the first parameter, try:

```
bIsConnected = axCZKEM1.Connect_Net("192.168.1.201", Convert.ToInt32(4370));
```

Comment: Please can you add any exception/error details to the question.

Comment: I tried registering dll file inside system32 folder but that showed me an error.              regsvr32 the module failed to load make sure the binary is stored at the specified path.. But registration was successful in SysWOW64 folder.I have 64 bit version of operating system.